How to populate the dynamic model in array with mongoose
I am trying to design MongoDB Database for chat application.
Users are two types and are defined as Client and Worker model respectively.
The chats are between these two types of users.
I am making Chat model and when making schema for it. I want to store the ids of chatters.
const chatSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    photo: {
      type: String,
      default: 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/9790/9790561.png',
    },
    chatName: {
      type: String,
    },
    users: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: function(){
          
        }
      },
    ],
    latestMessage: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Message',
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

And I want to populate users field properly whether it is Client or Worker.
How can I do this?
I was trying to use dynamic ref but can't go further.
Please help me
refPath or dynamic refs seems to be solution but didn't find correct one.

Does this answer help?
